# How to tell if current component is on top in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to suspend some timeouts while a component is in the background.

Is it possible to tell when if the current component is at the top of the navigation stack, and therefor visible in react-native.

And is it possible to tell when some other component was poped or removed from the stack to make the current component visible?